# fancybox not showing div color?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, fancybox

I am loading `<div>` in fancybox.`<div>` has background color `Red`. But css is not loading in it.  What could be wrong?

```html
<div id="divForm" style="display: none;" class="error">
    An error has occurred on the page.
</div>
```

```js
function display_dialog() {
        $.fancybox.open({
            modal:true,
            content: $("#divForm").html(),
            padding: 5,
            openEffect: 'fade',
            openSpeed: 'normal',
            closeEffect: 'elastic',
            closeSpeed: 'slow'

        });
}
```

```css
 .error {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding:15px 10px 15px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
    color: #D8000C;
    background-color: #FFBABA;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you have like `.css` for `#divform` ? or you can try : `#divForm .error{...}`

Comment: Not sure. but Try `$("#divForm").text()` instead `$("#divForm").html()`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `content: $("#divForm").html()`. This gets the html from inside `#divForm` and not the actual `#divForm`. So with this you're loosing all your styles because there's no `.error` class to match against.

You should set the actual `#divForm` element as the content, and not what is inside the `#divForm`.

From [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

> .html()
>
> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements

If in your HTML you have a direct parent over `#divForm`, select that parent and use `.html()` on it. Example:

```
<div class="bananas">
    <div id="divForm" style="display: none;" class="error">
        An error has occurred on the page.
    </div>
</div>
```

Then do:

`content: $(".bananas").html();`

Comment: I removed `.html()`. still the same

Comment: If in your HTML you have a direct parent over `#divForm`, select that parent and use `.html()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
content: $("#divForm").html(),
```

by

```
href: "#divForm",
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gr7uw/)**

Also, bear in mind that if you are using `modal: true` you may need to set a way to close the box manually or automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="divForm" style="display: none;">
    <div class="error">
        An error has occurred on the page.
    </div>
</div>
```